# CSP Content Security Policy Ajax calls blocked

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, http-headers

I'm using NWebSec nuget package in my MVC core 2.2 application
If i run this code my Ajax calls are blocked
Any idea;

```
 //CSP Content Security Policy
        app.UseCsp(options => options
            .DefaultSources(s => s.Self())
            .ScriptSources(s => s.Self().UnsafeInlineSrc = true) // allow inline script
            .ScriptSources(x=> x.Self().UnsafeEvalSrc = true) // allow events
            .ConnectSources(x=> x.Self().NoneSrc = true)
            .StyleSources(s=> s.Self().UnsafeInlineSrc = true));
```

My Ajax call is:

```
showPleaseWait();
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("GetData", "DataGenerator")",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: { filter: selectedKeys },
        success:  function (d) {
            hidePleaseWait();
            window.location = "@Url.RouteUrl(new { Controller = "DataGenerator", Action = "downloadDocx"})/?fileName=" + d.filename;
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            hidePleaseWait();
            alert("Error: Please refresh the page and try again!\n" + "Status:"+status + "\nError: " + error + "\nxhr.status: " + xhr.status + "\nxhr.statusText: " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
```

My Modal code is:

```
  function showPleaseWait() {

    if (document.querySelector("#modalPush") == null) {
        var modalLoading = '<div class="modal" id="pleaseWaitDialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" role="dialog">\
        <div class="modal-dialog">\
            <div class="modal-content">\
                <div class="modal-header">\
                   <h4 class="modal-title">\
                     <span > Generating your report....</span> \
                    </h4>\
                </div>\
                <div class="modal-body">\
                    <div class="progress">\
                      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>\
                      </div>\
                    </div>\
         <div class="modal-footer">\
           <span > Please wait ....</span> \
            </div>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
    </div>';
        $(document.body).append(modalLoading);
    }

    $("#pleaseWaitDialog").modal("show");
}

function hidePleaseWait() {
    $("#pleaseWaitDialog").modal("hide");
}
```

Comment: can you add the call that is being blocked for more context?

Comment: Is there any sort of error message you can show us?